# For LinqToSQL is 0 true or is 1 (for type Bit)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a column of type Bit (called BBoolVal in this example).

I have a LinqToSQL Statement Like this:

```
var query = List<MyClass> myList = _ctx.DBList
              .Where(x => x.AGuidID == paramID) 
              .Where(x => x.BBoolVal == false);
```

When I look at the sql it ends up like this (I added the spacing and changed the names):

```
SELECT    [t0].[Id], [t0].[AGuidID], [t0].[OtherIDID], 
          [t0].[TimeColumn], [t0].[BBoolVal], [t0].[MoreID]
FROM      [dbo].[MyTable] AS [t0]
WHERE (NOT ([t0].[BBoolVal] = 1)) AND ([t0].[AGuidID] = @p0)
```

Because my x.BBoolVal == false translates to [BBoolVal] == 1 I gather that false = 1 (and thus true = 0).

I am asking because this seems a bit backwards to me.  I am fine to accept it, I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice it says WHERE (**NOT** ([t0].[BBoolVal] = 1)) AND ([t0].[AGuidID] = @p0)

While is is really odd that it did that, it is effectively the same as [t0].[BBoolVal] = 0

EDIT

---

Giving it some thought, this way BBoolVal will match on False or NULL (assuming that BBoolVal is nullable).

Comment: Doesn't `NULL` only match when explicitly selected with `IS NULL` and excluded in all other cases when comparing with that column?

Comment: Not in this case.  Not(BBoolVal = 1) means that BBoolVal can be 0, or it can be null and still evaluate to true, Where (BBoolVal = 0) would evaluate to false if BBoolVal was null.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `NOT` before your `[BBoolVal] = 1`, so it's all like you initially expected—a boolean `true` is `1` and `false` is probably zero.

Comment: Still, the code generated is kind of weird. Do you know how this comes?

Comment: totally missed the NOT.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1 is true, 0 is false; but a Bool.Parse() works on the .ToString() value.